# Integrating Bootstrap Admin page to Laravel 5.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, angular-ui-bootstrap, laravel-5.4

I have a requirement of creating an admin page in my Laravel website. I know it could have been from the scratch but I loved how bootstrap had some amazing looking admin dashboard templates. 
I haven't started editing the template, but I want to make sure if my idea of integrating is right. I use Laravel 5.4 and could anyone tell me the basic process of integrating the template into the Laravel framework.

Highly appreciate your time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create .blade.php files on /resources/views and assets (bootstrap, images etc) on /public directory.

On .blade.php file you can call `asset('bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css')` that you saved on /public directory. 
There is another way without asset() function 'bootstrap/boostrap.min.css' it will work but its recommended to use asset because It could be more complicated latter

On controller only return view.

Or you can separate laravel and front-end on different folders and link them using API.